# How can i horizontally stack these thumbnails?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do i go about getting these to sit side by side as shown here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails-custom-content

As it is now they are stacked on top of one another.
I know there is some css to be done but im not very familiar with any of this.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the thumbnails on the same line, you need to have them in the same wrapping div with a row class.

Take a look at the grid documentation for a full explanation of how to do layouts with bootstrap. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```